# Casting float to int with wrap-around on aarch64/arm64

Tags: c++, clang, arm64, floating-point-conversion

I'm trying to match the behavior exactly between an application running on both x86_64 and aarch64/arm64. However, they differ in how they cast a floating point number to an integer when it's outside of the possible range of integers.

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>

void cast(float value) {
  printf("uint32_t(%.2f) = %u\n", value, uint32_t(value));
}

int main() {
  cast(4294967808.);
}

# output on x86_64:  uint32_t(4294967808.00) = 512
# output on aarch64: uint32_t(4294967808.00) = 4294967295
```

The x86_64 version is using [cvttss2si](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttss2si) for the conversion, which wraps-around the answer, although the documentation is quite unclear on this. Aarch64 is using [fcvtzu](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-Floating-point-Instructions/FCVTZU--scalar--fixed-point-) which is saturating.

Any solution to align the two would be interesting, but ideally I'd like to set a compiler flag on clang to have the aarch64 version behave like the x86_64 one (even though the aarch64 is "nicer")

Comment: The behavior is undefined. Also, ARM has a special instruction for this, because javascript has specified this behavior (which is undefined in C) to be the behavior of x86, because of course javascript would do such a thing. So to run javascript quickly, ARM had to invent an instruction doing something stupid that nobody could ever want because of a bad language that too many people are using.

Comment: @EOF Well, defining a behaviour isn't a bad design choice and returning a sentinel value isn't inherently bad either.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Do you know what that instruction is, EOF? Because I sure couldn't find it!

Comment: Actually, EOF, you set me on the right track! The instruction is `fjcvtzs` (intrinsic `__builtin_arm_jcvt`). Thanks!

Comment: [Why do ARM chips have an instruction with Javascript in the name (FJCVTZS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50966676/995714)

Comment: `cvttss2si` doesn't wrap-around.  To do float->uint32_t, the compiler will use it with 64-bit operand-size.  i.e. it uses `(uint32_t)(int64_t)f` because that's how x86-64 can do it in one instruction.  The high 32 bits of the 64-bit register aren't part of its value as a `uint32_t`.  If the value was even larger, outside the range of `int64_t`, you'd get `0` (the low half of the integer-indefinite value the x86 manual documents, `0x8000000000000000`.)  TL:DR: you need to look at what destination register width `cvttss2si` is used with; that determines what the the overflow cutoff is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the CPU instruction [fjcvtzs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-Floating-point-Instructions/FJCVTZS) (or the intrinsic `__builtin_arm_jcvt`) to get behavior of x86 on aarch64.

(Thanks to @EOF for providing enough information in a comment for me to find the answer)

Comment: You could have asked him to reword his comment as an answer but that's just me