# compiling on an ARM64 system using g++, avoid using the built-in fcvtzu and instead use g++'s cvttss2si

Tags: g++, arm64

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    float f = -1500;
    unsigned int i = f;

    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In an ARM-based operating system, when a negative floating-point number is converted to an unsigned integer, the result is typically 0. On the other hand, in an x86-based operating system, when a negative floating-point number is converted to an unsigned integer, the result may be a large unsigned integer that corresponds to the bit pattern of the original floating-point number.compiling on an ARM64 system using g++, avoid using the built-in fcvtzu and instead use g++'s cvttss2si
By adding compilation options, I hope to obtain a good solution`

Comment: Wdym "g++'s cvttss2si"? `cvttss2si` is an x86 instruction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting float to int with wrap-around on aarch64/arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279679/casting-float-to-int-with-wrap-around-on-aarch64-arm64)